# while not working inside main

Tags: c, winapi, while-loop

I wanted to try some win32 functions to manage files.
In particular, i wanted to create a program that gets a file as input, and print it out as reversed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void prova()
{
    int z = 0;
        while(z<5)
        {
            puts("Helloworld!");
            z++;
        }
}

int m = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LPDWORD lpFileSizeHigh;
    HANDLE file;
    file = CreateFile(
            argv[1],
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);

    if(file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error on opening the file: %x", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(file, lpFileSizeHigh);

    CloseHandle(file);

    printf("fileSize:   %d\n", fileSize );


    prova();

    while(m<5)
    {
        puts("Hello, world!");
        m++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For sake of clarity and brevity i rearrenged the code and removed the not-reached reversing part.

This code acutally works well, it prints out 10 times Hello, World. BUT, if you define the m variable inside the main function, it stops responding for some reason.
If i remove the file releated code, it starts working again O_o
I'm a noob at c language since i haven't much experience but i can't understand why it does this.

I'm on windows 8, using Eclipse and mingw.

Comment: When you declared it inside of `main()` did you also initialize it to 0?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info. Learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: @FatalError I cut-paste the code you see (int m=0) inside the main after the brackets.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This code works. As i said, just move the int m=0 inside the main and than it will not work. Is that so difficult? Next time i'll copy 2 times the whole code because you can't cut-paste one line ;)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Debugger dosen't help me, since it gets terminated too. Seems like it gets killed after DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(file, lpFileSizeHigh); Thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe try another debugger (some port of `gdb` to your proprietary operating system)...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yep. If i move the declaration of m the program stops working. If it didn't stop the i wouldn't make this question ;). As you can see, i got the answer so thanks anyway ;)

Comment: People frequently post here and describe their code, but do it wrong. That's why we like to see the actual code that is under consideration. Otherwise we wonder if the real problem is in the code that the asker has that is different from that in the question.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LPDWORD lpFileSizeHigh;
```

This allocates a pointer, but does not initialize it.

```
DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(file, lpFileSizeHigh);
```

This passes that uninitialized pointer to `GetFileSize`, and at that point anything can happen.

Declare a variable:

```
DWORD FileSizeHigh;
```

And pass its address:

```
DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(file, &FileSizeHigh);
```

FWIW, `GetFileSizeEx` is a little easier to use.